# How to get the date difference in minus value in PHP

Tags: php, date, difference

I'm trying to get the date difference in minus value if the start_Date is greater than the end_date. below is my code

```
    $diff =  strtotime('2019-07-31') - strtotime('2019-07-21');
    $date_diff = round($diff / 86400);
```

the code gives me `10` as answer, but i want `-10`. how should i get it?

Comment: `$diff =  strtotime('2019-07-21') - strtotime('2019-07-31');`?

Comment: @Nick what do you mean to ask?

Comment: Just write the code the other way around (end-start) instead of (start-end)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to use `%r` format. This format prints a minus (-) sign if the difference is negative, or nothing otherwise.

```
<?php

function dateDifference($date_1 , $date_2 , $differenceFormat = '%r%a' ) {
    $datetime1 = date_create($date_1);
    $datetime2 = date_create($date_2);

    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

    return $interval->format($differenceFormat);

}

echo dateDifference('2019-07-31', '2019-07-21'); // -10
```

Answer (score 2):

Here it is. just put a negative sign before rounding.

```
$diff =  strtotime('2019-07-31') - strtotime('2019-07-21');
$date_diff =  - round($diff / 86400); // here is the change you need

echo $date_diff;
```

Output:

```
-10
```